# In LINQ, how to use Int? optionally in where condition

Tags: linq, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have a LINQ script and I am getting SiteId optional. So I want to select all the records if SiteId = 0 or int? else get records where siteId of given value

```
            var queryResult = (from schedule in GetAll<EziScheduleEntity>()
                               where 
                                    schedule.StartTime < endTime && schedule.EndTime > startTime
                                 && schedule.SiteId == SiteId  //this SiteId is of Type int? 
                               select schedule
                                   );
```

..

```
   && schedule.SiteId == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringSiteId) == false? stringSiteId ||  )
```

Comment: You can use `||`: `(schedule.SiteId == 0 || schedule.SiteId == SiteId)`

Comment: I am unable to syntax right, can you kindly provide me complete . thanks

Comment: I have tried as following but not sure how I say to ignore condition is there is no value in SiteId?

Comment: && schedule.SiteId == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringSiteId) == false? stringSiteId ||  )

Comment: `&& schedule.SiteId ==  SiteId.HasValue ? SiteId : 0)` default value is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the local variable `SiteId` is of type `int?`, then just test it for a value:

```
var queryResult = (from schedule in GetAll<EziScheduleEntity>()
                   where
                        schedule.StartTime < endTime &&
                        schedule.EndTime > startTime &&
                        (SiteId.HasValue ? schedule.SiteId == SiteId : true)
                   select schedule
                  );
```

Alternatively, you can use boolean logic to accomplish the same thing:

```
var queryResult = (from schedule in GetAll<EziScheduleEntity>()
                   where
                        schedule.StartTime < endTime &&
                        schedule.EndTime > startTime &&
                        (!SiteId.HasValue || schedule.SiteId == SiteId)
                   select schedule
                  );
```